# Make msysgit work with cygwin ssh?

Tags: git, cygwin, openssh, sshd, msysgit

git-upload-pack errors occur when sshing into cygwin. `sshd` in cygwin does not take paths from `.bash_profile` as expected in a *nix environment.

What is the way to remedy this and make msysgit work properly with cygwin bash and cygwin ssh?

Comment: Please frame this as a question and post your answer in the below section meant for answers. Thanks.

Comment: Done it's now a wiki.

Answer (score 1):

I looked every where with people getting git-upload-pack missing errors like myself and came up with this.

**Basicly this just sets Cygwins ssh path to have msysgit in it**

- Install msysgit (use git bash only should be enough we don't need the git.cmd thing for cygwin)
- Install cygwin search for ssh and tick/check it.

  ```
  ssh-host-config -y
  ```

  I didn't bother setting the CYGWIN var to anything the defaults seemed correct.

  ```
  cygrunsrv.exe -R sshd
  ```

remove the service that was created in the process

```
    ssheNv="/usr/bin:/bin:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/bin"

    mSysgit="/usr/local/bin:/c/WINDOWS/system32:/c/WINDOWS:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Git/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Git/libexec/git-core"
```

now add these two strings to the path below:

```
    cygrunsrv -I sshd -d "CYGWIN sshd" -p /usr/sbin/sshd -a -D -e "PATH=$ssheNv:$mSysgit"

    cygrunsrv.exe -S
```

start the service (use -E to stop again if you want)

## from another PC with msysgit

```
git clone  ssh://dude@hostIPetc'/Documents and Settings/blabla/myrepo.git'
```

For this people that didn't have `git-upload-pack` in their path well this fixes it. I don't have to install cygwin git just to satisfy paths!

Question though can any one figure out how to point to cygwin paths "/cygdrive/d/" etc? right now only / works and that means C:\

If anyone thinks this is all to sloppy and one should just use cygwin git please say so.

hmm http://www.grumpydev.com/2011/01/19/switching-from-cygwin-to-msysgit-git-thinks-everything-has-been-modified/
MSysGit “fakes” filemodes is that a reason to switch to cygwin or is it helpfull on windows...